# Justify if it is possible to interchange the integral sign and the series: a series involving the Möbius function and loggamma terms

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, gamma-function

Let for integers $n\geq 1$ the Möbius function $\mu(n)$, you can see the definition of this arithmetic function from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html), and let  $\Gamma(s)$ the Gamma function. I would like to know how to justify, if it is feasible, that the integral sign and the infinite series can be interchanged here

$$\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\log\Gamma(x+n)\right)dx.\tag{1}$$

Notice that if it is possible to provide a justification that the integral sign and summation can be interchanged, then symbolically one can to calculate a closed-form of the resulting $RHS$, using a theorem due to Raabe ([1], or well the Wikipedia's article dedicated to Joseph Ludwig Raabe) and standard series involving the Möbius function (this includes the prime number theorem).

Using experiments I try to see if I can swap the order or the summation and the integration. For example I believe (my experiments were sparsed and the quantities are oscillating around the mentioned closed-form) that $$\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N=70}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\log\Gamma(x+n)\right)dx\approx -0.4379544$$
but with upper limit $N=80$ in the sum of previous integrand I know that 
my approximation gets worse again.

> **Question.** Is it possible to interchange the integral sign and summation here $$\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\log\Gamma(x+n)\right)dx\,?$$
>   **Many thanks.**

I think that it isn't in the literature, but feel free if it was to refer answering this as a reference request. I know how to calculate the mentioned closed-form, thus I am asking exclusively about how to justify/discard that the integral sign and the series can be interchanged.

### References:

[1] T. Amdeberhan, M. Coffey, O. Espinosa, C. Koutschan, D. Manna, and V. Moll, 
*Integrals of powers of loggamma*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc., 139(2):535–545, (2010).